# Regex find/replace stops after first word

Tags: regex, shell

Why is only one of "the" replaced in the string if I set \g for global?

```
sed -E 's/(^|_)(the|an|is)(_|$)/\1/g' <<< "the_the_river"
= the_river
```

Comment: Because the second `_` is consumed during the first iteration.

Comment: Ah I see, is there a way to fix this within the regex or do I have to resort to looping?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I would like to have all the word the|an|is removed from the string. Hopefully have this work both osx and gnu as well

Comment: Why are you replacing with `\1` then? Try `sed -E 's/(the|an|is)//g' <<< "the_the_river"` or `sed -E 's/(the|an|is)(_)//g' <<< "the_the_river"`

Comment: In which case `-r` should be used instead of `-E`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I think Newton wants to test for word boundary too.

Comment: Alternative: `echo "the_the_river" | perl -pe 's/(?<![^_])(?:the|an|is)(?:_|$)//g'`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the problem is, that latter `_` is consumed. To avoid overlapping matches you need either [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Word boundaries like `\<`, `\>` or some versions `\b` cannot be used in your case because the underscore belongs to *word characters*.

Alternative can be a [perl one-liner](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-perl-one-liners.html) that uses PCRE which supports lookarounds.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<![^_])(?:the|an|is)(?:_|$)//g' <<< "the_the_river"
```

> river

- `(?<![^_])` is a negative lookbehind that checks if before the word there is not any character [besides](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) underscore. It matches at *start* or any position right before an underscore.
- `(?:the|an|is)` is a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [alternating](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) the different words.
- `(?:_|$)` assuming you want to remove (consume) the underscore after word.

[See regex101 for testing the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/5t79EG/1)